# Why I am getting zero output for all the values in array?

Tags: c++, graph, input, matching

I got this implementation for maximum matching off the net and is trying to give its input through main class. But I am getting zero for all the places in match. What am I doing wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream> 
#include <queue>
using namespace std;
void add_edge(int u, int v);
void edmonds();
struct edge {
   int v, nx;
};
const int MAXN = 1000, MAXE = 2000;
edge graph[MAXE];
int last[MAXN], match[MAXN], px[MAXN], base[MAXN], N, M, edges;

bool used[MAXN], blossom[MAXN], lused[MAXN];

int main ()
{
//  return 0;
   add_edge(1,4);
   add_edge(1,5);
   add_edge(1,6);
   add_edge(2,5);
   add_edge(2,7);
   add_edge(3,4);
   add_edge(4,1);
   add_edge(4,3);
   add_edge(5,1);
   add_edge(5,2);
   add_edge(6,1);
   add_edge(7,2);
   edmonds();
   cout << match[0];
   cout << match[1];
   cout << match[2];
   cout << match[3];
   cout << match[4];
   cout << match[5];
   cout << match[6];
}

inline void add_edge(int u, int v) {
   graph[edges] = (edge) {v, last[u]};
   last[u] = edges++;
   graph[edges] = (edge) {u, last[v]};
   last[v] = edges++;
}

void mark_path(int v, int b, int children) {
   while (base[v] != b) {
      blossom[base[v]] = blossom[base[match[v]]] = true;
      px[v] = children;
      children = match[v];
      v = px[match[v]];
   }
}

int lca(int a, int b) {
   memset(lused, 0, N);
   while (1) {
      lused[a = base[a]] = true;
      if (match[a] == -1)
         break;
      a = px[match[a]];
   }
   while (1) {
      b = base[b];
      if (lused[b])
         return b;
      b = px[match[b]];
   }
}
int find_path(int root) {
   memset(used, 0, N);
   memset(px, -1, sizeof(int) * N);
   for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
      base[i] = i;
   used[root] = true;
   queue<int> q;
   q.push(root);
   register int v, e, to, i;
   while (!q.empty()) {
      v = q.front(); q.pop();
      for (e = last[v]; e >= 0; e = graph[e].nx) {
         to = graph[e].v;
         if (base[v] == base[to] || match[v] == to)
            continue;
         if (to == root || (match[to] != -1 && px[match[to]] != -1)) {
            int curbase = lca(v, to);
            memset(blossom, 0, N);
            mark_path(v, curbase, to);
            mark_path(to, curbase, v);
            for (i = 0; i < N; ++i)
               if (blossom[base[i]]) {
                  base[i] = curbase;
                  if (!used[i]) {
                     used[i] = true;
                     q.push(i);
                  }
               }
         } else if (px[to] == -1) {
            px[to] = v;
            if (match[to] == -1)
               return to;
            to = match[to];
            used[to] = true;
            q.push(to);
         }
      }
   }
   return -1;
}
void build_pre_matching() {
   register int u, e, v;
   for (u = 0; u < N; ++u)
      if (match[u] == -1)
         for (e = last[u]; e >= 0; e = graph[e].nx) {
            v = graph[e].v;
            if (match[v] == -1) {
               match[u] = v;
               match[v] = u;
               break;
            }
         }
}

void edmonds() {
   memset(match, 0xff, sizeof(int) * N);
   build_pre_matching();
   register int i, v, pv, ppv;
   for (i = 0; i < N; ++i)
      if (match[i] == -1) {
         v = find_path(i);
         while (v != -1) {
            pv = px[v], ppv = match[pv];
            match[v] = pv, match[pv] = v;
            v = ppv;
         }
      }
}
```

Comment: I didn't read the whole thing, but edges should be initialized to 0, and N and M seem to be constants but aren't initialized either. Try starting with that.

Answer (score 0):

You set elements of `match` in two locations: In `build_pre_matching()` and in `edmonds()`. In both of these cases, no change will happen if `match[x]` for some index `x` isn't `-1`. The only other place elements of `match` get a value is during static initialization where the values get zero initialized. Since the initial value is zero and the values are only ever changed if at least one of them happens to be `-1`, I would expect that the values retain the value `0`.

You might want to use something like

```
std::fill(std::begin(match), std::end(match), -1);
```

at a strategic location since you seem to assume that the values are initially `-1`. Of course, you also should consider the idea of **not** using global variables because this doesn't scale and works really badly in a multi-threaded program.